# Oracle linux front end

Tags: linux, oracle, frontend

Is there any Oracle database ( around version 10 ) front end that we can use in Linux, free or open source?

I am currently using Ubuntu 8.10 and if possible I just want it to need the thin JDBC to connect to oracle and not the whole (huge) client of oracle installed in it.

Answer (score 4):

I use [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html) which is similar to TOAD (which is not free).  SQL Developer is free and supported by Oracle.  Make sure you get the latest version as they're improving it all the time.  It has a nice graphical UI and support for editing PL/SQL stored procedures.  I think there are even plugins for other databases (like MySQL).

Its a Java application and there is a Linux distribution, though I use the Windows version.  It does not require an Oracle client, though it does support one, like the [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/oci/instantclient/index.html), should you have it installed.

Answer (score 2):

seems like http://tora.sourceforge.net/ is the opensource version of toad

also there is http://oss.oracle.com/sqldeveloper.html

Comment: TOra is good. I don't think its related to Toad in any way, or may be just the names feel like from similar origin.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much any JDBC tool will be able to talk compentantly to Oracle.

I've used SQuirrel SQL Client, SQL Workbench, DbVisualizer (free edition).
There's even plug-ins for jEdit that can talk to a database.